# List of strings: remove and split elements to extract words

Tags: python, regex

I have the following two different cases of list of strings:

```
my_list1=['_','net_my_name','_64', '_66']
my_list2=['net_another_file']
```

I would like to extract

- `net_my_name` as `my name` in case I have type of lists such as `my_list1`;
- `net_another_file` as `another file` in case I have type of lists such as `my_list2`.

To do so, I was thinking of:

- in case I find a situation like that one described by `my_list1`, then remove elements that are numerical, then split on `_` to take the last two items (i.e. `my name`);
- in case I find a situation like that one described by `my_list2`, then split on `_` to take the last two items (i.e. `another file`).

If I removed numerical values, where they occur, I would have `my_name` as last word, i.e. `my name` as last two words.

Expected output:

```
my name
another file
```

Can you please tell me how to 'translate' in code the steps above? Thank you

Comment: so you want to extract strings that start with `net_`...?

Comment: this is very confusing,is my_name equal to net_my_name

Comment: what do you mean by "case like list1' and 'case like list2'? What are the criteria for these two cases?

Comment: Give better examples please

Comment: I noticed the error. Thank you @Chase and coderftheday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
import re
string = "net_another_file777"
string = re.sub("[0-9]", "", string)   # "net_another_file"
L = string.split('_')[-2:]   # ['another', 'file']
```

Now you have just to go through the list and aply this to every element in the list.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much ThunderPheonix. Just a note: since it was a list of strings, I   used this `string=" ".join(str(x) for x in string)` just to transform it in a string.

Comment: @LucaDiMauro Yes you can do that too.